# typedef and multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    typedef int Array[2];

    int Sum(Array A[], int n)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
           for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
              sum += A[i][j];

        return sum;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int n = 2, sum;
        Array A[n];

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
           for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
               A[i][j] = i * n + j;

        cout << Sum(A, n) << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

It is good to use typedef in global scope?
It is good to use typedef to declare multi-dimensional array, instead of A[][]?

Comment: `p = new Array;` -- that means I say `delete p`, right? -- Average Joe.

Comment: @KerrekSB Are you saying that it confusing because in fact you must go `delete p[]` or what? Its a very interesting point. Is that even valid syntax?

Comment: `A[]` is not really an array and `A[][]` is not really a multidimentional array and such expressions should be avoided completely. Also I must mention that `Array A[n];` is illegal as `n` is not a constant expression.

Comment: @pm100: Yes, and yes.

Comment: In C++ we already have `std::array` and `std::vector`. What advantage does `Array` bring us?